# Where does access list comes from in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Can anyone suggest where from access list comes in Joomla? This list is available when creating 'Category' or 'Article' as:

[image]

I check and this is rendering from edit.php via

```
echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.edit.global', $this);
```

Though actually the whole section(right side panel) is being rendered from this function. If we see the Ids associated with each dropdown, they are different from userGroup ids of Joomla, and also 'Special' is not a userGroup altogether. From which method they are getting prepared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between user groups and access level.[image]

For understanding this I suggest you this tutorial: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Access_Control_List_Tutorial